# jQuery UI Datepicker - setDate not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I know this question has been asked on SO before, but I can't figure out what I'm missing.  Here is a simple [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nosfan1019/tbYPf/1/).

The jquery:

```
var myDate = new Date(1978,2,11) 
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', myDate);
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have to initialize the datepicker first:

```
    $('#datepicker').datepicker();
```

When you pass setDate, you are calling a method which assumes the datepicker has already been initialized on that object.

http://jsfiddle.net/tbYPf/4/

Comment: How did you knew that? If I look at the documentation http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate I do not see any note that it has to be called after datpicker has been first initialized.

Comment: Worked! Been looking the 1 whole day for this! I was close to insanity! No seriously thanks man! It's not mentioned in the documentation I think.