# set jquery datepicker date by using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

i am setting the datepicker date and trying to show the datepicker by the following way

```
    $('.shw-dt').datepicker({
        dateFormat : "mm/dd/yyyy",
        setDate :"09/19/2014"
    });
```

But datepicker is always showing todays date. Looks like the value is not set which i am trying to set. Any ideas

Comment: Might this be it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962747/jquery-ui-datepicker-setdate-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[setDate()](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate) is a function so you need to use

```
$('.shw-dt').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy"
}).datepicker('setDate', "09/19/2014");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wroqcw7p/)

Answer (score 0):

Set your datePicker date using **setdate** function.

```
$('#dateselector').datepicker("setDate", new Date(2014,1,01) );
```

You should look into documentation of DatePicker first.