# How to set the default date to two days from current date using date picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

I went through many examples but Im not able to set the value of my date picker. The textbox value is shown as 01/01/2016 and the calendar opens to that date as well. Im trying to set the default date to two days from now in the text box as well as in the calendar that shows up on click. 
I tried the following:

1.

```
$(".date-picker").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

2.

```
$(".date-picker").datepicker().datepicker('setDate', '+2');
```

My HTML is:

```
<input type="text" class="input date-picker">
```

I agree this question has been repeated lots of times but I have tried most of the examples but still Im not able to make it work. Please advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI Datepicker - setDate not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962747/jquery-ui-datepicker-setdate-not-working)

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date and put the someDate-variable or the someFormattedDate  variable where new Date() is right now

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery UI datepicker default date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829033/jquery-ui-datepicker-default-date)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this is to extend the javascript date function using prototype

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
this.setDate(this.getDate() + days);
return this;
};
```

Then simply call as follows:-

```
$(function() {
var currentDate = new Date();

var myDate = currentDate.addDays(2);

$(".date-picker").datepicker(); //initialise
$(".date-picker").datepicker('setDate', myDate); //set date

});
```

DONT FORGET you have to INITIALISE the datepicker - then set the date

[JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/g948crqL/)

Comment: The JS Fiddle shows the exact way I want it, but somehow when I use it my webpage, the calendar still opens at 01/01/2016 and the default date in the text box is also the same date

Comment: Change it from a class to an ID then try it - my guess is you have some stray code setting a date somewhere else. At least this way we can rule that out

Comment: I changed the HTML to this:
`<input id="date-picker" type ="text" >`

I still have the same problem.

Comment: you got it sorted then?

Comment: Yeah. It had something to do with my HTML I guess. When I used id it didnt even pull up the calendar. I changed my HTML to 
`<input type="text" class="date-picker">`
which worked.

Comment: if you change it to an ID don't forget you have to update the javascript selector to #date-picker from .date-picker. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a datepicker with the defaultDate option specified.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".date-picker").datepicker({
        defaultDate: +2,
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy"
    });
});
```

Comment: I have my code like this:
 `$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".date-picker" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: +2 });
});
$(".date-picker").datepicker({dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",  defaultDate: "+2d"}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());`

It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/8ejbw8d5/

```
$( ".date-picker" ).datepicker({
  defaultDate: +2
});
// Getter
var defaultDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate" );

// Setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", +2 );
```

Read more here: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate